# SWFLoader doens't work twice

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a game that dynamicaly loads another minigame.

I load it using `SWFLoader`:

```
function loadMinigame(minigameName:String):void
{
    var loader:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader;
    loader.load("/Content/Swf/" + minigameName + ".swf");
    layerMinigames.addElement(loader);
}
```

The first time I load it works nice. But when I exit the minigame and try to open it again via same method it doens't apper in my application (sometimes do sometimes doens't).

Both games are Flex application.

What's going on?

**Update**

I did `loader.loadForCompatibility = true` and now it loads properly! But now I'm getting an error when I try to cast the result:

```
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void
{
    var sys:SystemManager = SystemManager(e.currentTarget.content);
});
```

gives:

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert
>   _AppMinigame1_mx_managers_SystemManager@14c97eb9 to mx.managers.SystemManager.

Comment: The other error is because your minigame is another SWF, thus its `ApplicationDomain` is different from your main SWF's, so even identical classes are different at runtime in these two SWFs. Probably do an object result cast instead. (Why do you need `SystemManager` out of that SWF?)

Comment: @Vesper I need to setup some data inside the minigame loaded, like change avatar. No success yet.

Comment: I think you should send strings or `Object`s into the minigame, probably by sending it custom events with `data` field containing an object to parse.

Comment: @Vesper what do you mean? calling `sys.dispatchEvent(new MiniEvent(objData))`?

Comment: `loader.content.dispatchEvent(new Event("customevent",objData))`. Check syntax though, and check what do you receive when listening to the event.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better cache the loaded minigame after loading, then just display it again when needed. Make sure though, that the minigame's `ADDED_TO_STAGE` listener resets the minigame properly.

```
static var loadedGames:Object={};
function loadMinigame(minigameName:String):void
{
    if (loadedGames[minigameName]==null) {
        var loader:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader;
        loader.load("/Content/Swf/" + minigameName + ".swf");
        loadedGames[minigameName]=loader;
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaderFinished);
    } else {
        layerMinigames.addElement(loadedGames[minigameName]);
    }
}
function loaderFinished(e:Event):void {
    layerMinigames.addElement(e.target);
    // do the rest, like setting proper start time for minigame, etc
}
```

UPDATE: Since you run out of memory while running such a process, this means that the minigame's instance holds onto too much memory, and needs to be freed (GC'd) in order to load another minigame. Thus, caching loading SWFs is out of question. You can release an SWF using `unloadAndStop()` call against it, prior to doing this, make sure that your minigame is removed from display list, and its `REMOVED_FROM_STAGE` listener shuts down every listener attached to `stage`. Also you might need to debug your minigame SWF to locate probable memory leaks, as your SWFs share the same memory space, and a memory leak in one of them nullifies your efforts to do anything in all the others.

Comment: I can't cache all minigames. But the same issue happens if i try to load another minigame...

Comment: You can't cache, meaning you run out of memory? Yep, this constraint is better prepared for. Then you can't solve your problem by loading all SWFs once and leave it at that. Probably you can cache a `prototype` of that SWF's `Main` class, dropping the expanded SWF and creating `new loadedGames[minigameName]()` whenever you need a new game instance. I'll update the answer.